How to control HTTP request frequency in a JMeter script with a while loop checking job status?
Question:
I'm working on a JMeter script that has to check for the status of a job through an HTTP request in an endless loop until it actually completes. The problem is that as soon as I use a While Controller to call the repeated checks for the job's status, the requests are so fast and rapid that performance problems occur-they will be hitting the server on multiple requests at the exact same time.
My aim is to introduce a delay between each request so that the server does not get overloaded while the script is not too long to execute. However, introducing a timer inside the While Controller results in a longer overall script runtime, which I would like to minimize.
Here's what I have tried so far:
Using timers inside the While Controller: To delay requests, but this slows down the overall script execution time.
Polling to see job completion: I regularly query the status of my job. However, I am currently getting too many simultaneous requests.
Can I control HTTP request frequencies such that:

It should not overload the system by multiple requests at one time
I have checked for completion efficiently of my job so that there is no flooding in the server

Any ideas on the most efficient way to control for timing of requests or rearranging the script to achieve it would be greatly appreciated!

Using a timer or Flow Control Action sampler is the way to go. It shouldn't increase test execution time more than the "sleep" time.
Alternatively you could use another Thread Group with 1 thread to check the job status, the job ID and status can be passed using i.e. Inter-Thread Communication Plugin
